# Autofill people/Group field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Is there a way to auto-fill people/group field based on a drop down choice for new form? For example, when the user select Choice A, people/group field would automatically fill in "Group A". I use sharepoint 2013 with Javascript.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try below method:

1. Create a list and add Choice, people column

[image]

2. Add below JS code:

/* code */

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[title='testchoice']").change(function () {
        console.log("Handler for .change() called.");

        if (this.value == "Choice A") {
            SetUserFieldValue("testUser", "SBdev Members");
        }

        if (this.value == "Choice B") {
            SetUserFieldValue("testUser", "SBdev Owners");
        }

    });
});
 
function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {
    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');

    var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
    
    while (_PeoplePickerOject.TotalUserCount > 0) {
        _PeoplePickerOject.DeleteProcessedUser();
    }

    var _PeoplePickerEditer = _PeoplePicker.find("input[id$='EditorInput']");
    _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);

    _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

}
```

Result:

[image]

***Note**: Please not forget to add Jquery refernce when you insert this code (Script editor webpart or JSlink).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

More References:

- https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/javascript-and-working-with-the-sharepoint-2013-people-picker/
- [In 2013 using JavaScript how do you empty a people picker field?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119008/in-2013-using-javascript-how-do-you-empty-a-people-picker-field)
- https://api.jquery.com/change/

BR

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your help with the code! Is it possible to check if the person is part of Choice A? If the person is not in Choice A, there would be an alert before submission?